# Check if all word fragments exist in a text

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I want to check if **all** given word fragments exist in any order in a given text.

The fragments are supplied by a web application user in a single string separated by spaces like *'abc xyz kj'*. They exist in *'mn kj qabc pc xyzw'* but do not exist in *'mn kj qabc pc xyw'*.

I wrote the following function which works but it looks quite convoluted so I must be doing it wrong. Any ideas on different approaches or how to make it perform?

BTW the database is read only for me so I can't full-text index it and the owners will not do it.

```
create function dbo.tem_fragmentos(
    @texto varchar(max), 
    @fragmentos varchar(max)
)
returns bit as
begin
    declare 
        @inicio integer = 1,
        @fim integer,
        @fragmento varchar(max);

    set @fragmentos = ltrim(rtrim(@fragmentos));
    while charindex('  ', @fragmentos) > 0
        set @fragmentos = replace(@fragmentos, '  ', ' ');

    while @inicio <= len(@fragmentos) begin
        set @fim = charindex(' ', @fragmentos, @inicio + 1);
        if @fim = 0 set @fim = len(@fragmentos) + 1;
        set @fragmento = substring(@fragmentos, @inicio, @fim - @inicio);
        if charindex(@fragmento, @texto) = 0 return 0;
        set @inicio = @fim + 1;
    end -- while
    return 1;
end;

select dbo.tem_fragmentos('clodoaldo pinto neto', ' clo cl nto pinto');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how I would do it. Not sure it's any less convoluted...

```
Create  Function dbo.tem_fragmentos
        (
            @texto varchar(max), 
            @fragmentos varchar(max)
        )
Returns Bit As
Begin   
        Declare @table Table (fragmentos Varchar(Max))
        Set     @fragmentos = Ltrim(Rtrim(@fragmentos))

        While @fragmentos <> ''
        Begin
                Insert  @table (fragmentos)
                Select  Left(@fragmentos,Charindex(' ',@fragmentos+' ')-1)

                Set     @fragmentos = Ltrim(Rtrim(Right(@fragmentos,Len(@fragmentos)-(Charindex(' ',@fragmentos+' ')-1))));
        end

        If      Exists (Select 1
                        From @table t
                        Where @texto Not Like '%' + fragmentos + '%')
        Begin
                Return 0;
        End
        Return 1;
End;

Select  dbo.tem_fragmentos('clodoaldo pinto neto', ' clo cl nto pinto');
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming your text exists in a db table, else you wouldn't have the db server doing the work. So, why not have your app break the string on spaces and build dynamic SQL like:

```
select *
from MyTable 
where charindex('abc', MyColumn) > 0
    and charindex('xyz', MyColumn) > 0
    and charindex('kj', MyColumn) > 0
```

**Update:**

If you don't want to use dynamic SQL, I would split the input into words in my application, and then pass the list of words in to the query using a table valued parameter (TVP). Then it is a simple left join to determine whether they all match or not.

Comment: I have been doing it like that for ages. But this time I will not dynamically build it as the whole query is quite complex and I want to keep my sanity.

Comment: Great to know about TVP. As I understand it is necessary to create a type to use it and I can't write to the DB.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a wildcarded `LIKE` search should work for you:

```
declare @texto varchar(max) = 'mn kj q abc pc xyzw', 
        @fragmentos varchar(max) = 'abc xyz kj'
/*
yes = 'mn kj qabc pc xyzw' 
 no = 'mn kj qabc pc xyw'
*/


--use your own number table
declare @number table (n int identity(1,1) primary key clustered, x char(1) null);
insert into @number(x)
    select top 1000 null from master..spt_values


select  [IsMatch] = min(case when @texto like '%'+substring(@fragmentos, n, charindex(' ', @fragmentos + ' ', n) - n)+'%' then 1 else 0 end)
from    @number
where   n <= datalength(@fragmentos)+1 and 
        substring(' ' + @fragmentos, N, 1) = ' ';
```